# Синтаксическая роль "по крайней мере" у меня

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, синтаксис

Приятель написал такое предложение:

> Мало кто это знает, по крайней мере у нас.

Он поставил запятую после *"по крайней мере",* посчитав его вводным сочетанием. Говорит, что как автор может без потери смысла опустить это выражение. А я говорю, что это присоединительная конструкция, если не ошибаюсь. То есть у нас относится к самому выражению, а не к первой части до запятой.

Рассудите нас, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*По крайней мере* - это вводное сочетание, но стоит оно в начале присоединительной конструкции, поэтому не выделяется отдельно, а только отделяется от первой части вместе с конструкцией.

4. > Если вводное слово (сочетание) стоит в начале или в конце
   >   обособленного оборота (обособления, уточнения, пояснения,
   >   присоединения), то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно не
   >   отделяется: А Пётр Петрович, по крайней мере по многим признакам,
   >   человек весьма почтенный (Дост.).

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила!